# Favourite Tag + Ignored Tag in the Filtered Questions overview not doing what I'd like/expect

Tags: support, ignored-tags, tag-watching

I really like to check out the Filtered Questions page based on Favourite Tags ([this place](https://stackexchange.com/filters/favorite-tags)) but am annoyed by the inclusion of questions with tags I've ignored.

To give a concrete example, I love googling around and trying to help people with `*-identification` questions (e.g. `story-identification` [on scifi.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) or `species-identification` [on biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/species-identification)).

There are subsets / overlaps of these tags where I know I'm useless though, like `short-stories` [on scifi.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-stories).

[image]

I figured I'd just add those to the ignored tags to filter them out, buuuut that's apparently not how that works.
The regular tag view on a specific site already greys out questions with ignored tags, but 'not even' that is happening in this view.

Concrete 'support' question, which of the following applies?

1. I overlooked something in my approach, which is otherwise correct. *(and here's how to fix that)*
2. There is another way to achieve this functionality. *(and here's how to do it)*
3. Right now there is no way to do what you're after, this is a weird edge-case. *(but I get where you're coming from)*

Thank you.

Comment: You can "hide questions in your ignored list" rather than greying them out. Edit your ignored tags on the homepage and select the option from the radio buttons. Might be worth trying that out.

Comment: I have a feeling that page is just not up to date with new features though. I for one didn't even know it existed. It's design also seems to be out of date. I assume it's just a forgotten about page.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Ooh, that sounds like it's a step at least. Any chance you could point me to those radiobuttons? I couldn't find them in the profile settings myself... also, yeah now that you mention it, I can imagine that page just not being actively maintained anymore.

Comment: Not in the profile settings. Go to the homepage of the site i.e. [scifi.se], then edit your ignored tags from the box on the side (might need to be the full site not mobile) and they appear in that dialogue. Not sure if they're in the profile settings somewhere.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Found it, thanks! As expected, no effect on the filtered questions page from my question, but as a workaround this is something at least. I appreciate the help!